# Entity Framework Virtual ICollection How to Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

First of all, I am new to Entity Framework etc and trying to figure some things out.  I have a model like this:

```
 public class EventInstance {

    [Column("EVENT_INSTANCE_ID")]
    public int EventInstanceID { get; set; }

    [Column("CUSTOMER_ID")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Column("EVENT_ID")]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Column("START_DATE_TIME")]
    public System.DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

}
```

I need to access a property in a table called EventTimeEventInstances but this table is not included in the model.  I have two questions.

If I add:

```
public virtual ICollection<EventTimeEventInstance> EventTimeInstances { get; set; }
```

Will that effect other areas of our application?

Secondly, how do I access the property from the ICollection in a query like this:

```
 public IQueryable<EventInstance> GetInstances(int scheduleID) {
            // only returning instances that are 3 months back
            DateTime dateRange = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-180);
            return EventDBContext.EventInstances.Where
                (x => x.CustomerID == MultiTenantID && x.StartDateTime >= dateRange)
                .OrderBy(x => x.StartDateTime).AsQueryable();
        }
```

I need to be able to add EventTimeInstances.EventTimeID == scheudleID to this query.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like that in your query:

```
public IQueryable<EventInstance> GetInstances(int scheduleID) 
{
    // only returning instances that are 3 months back
    DateTime dateRange = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-180);
    return EventDBContext.EventInstances.Where(x => 
            x.CustomerID == MultiTenantID && 
            x.StartDateTime >= dateRange && 
            x.EventTimeInstances.Any(a => a.EventTimeID == scheudleID) ).OrderBy(x => x.StartDateTime).AsQueryable();
}
```